# Getting the same result, even after changes, when running code in Spyder IPython console

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

So I'm working on a problem for my programming course "6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python", and I've now run into some issues.

I'd gotten very close to the solution for the problem, but my answer was a little off. I went in and started making changes to the code. But as I pressed run (I'm using Spyder), the Ipython console gave me the exact same answer as before. I grew a little suspicious and started removing large chunks of code. Still the same answer. At the end I'd removed so much code that I only had a few completely irrelevant lines left and there was absolutely no way it should work. Yet it did, even after changing the input, it did exactly what it had done earlier.

Now, I'm a total beginner so I bet I've just missed something, but I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain to me what's going on.

```
annualInterestRate = 0.2

monthlyint = annualInterestRate/12

balance = 320000
epsilon = 0.5

print(round(guess,2))
```

According to what I've learnt this code shouldn't work (the round variable for example isn't even defined), and makes pretty much no sense. However, when I input it into the console it gives me:

```
29591.88
```

Why the heck does this happen?

[Here's a picture of it in my console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHkE9.png)

Comment: I'm guessing because you defined a work directory in line 10 of the console.  If you close Spyder or change the work directory, then the above code will fail because 'guess' is not defined

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know of a workaround that would prevent this kind of behaviour?

Comment: either delete the file in the work directory that has the function 'guess' or change the work directory to something else. Not sure what you mean by 'this kind of behaviour' because spyder is acting the way it should. it seems

Comment: Hm ok I'm just very confused, the problem I'm having isn't just the guess variable, but the fact that I can't edit my code and then immediately rerun it to see how it works then. I guess that's not how it's supposed to work but it just seems a little inconvenient.

Comment: How about running it from the editor and not from the console? does that work for you?

Comment: Well that's what I've been mostly doing, but the same problem persists. I also tried disabling the working directory when running it (from the editor) but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You're in the same Python session, no? The variables do not get cleared every time you give it a new input.

Comment: Yea I guess, makes more sense that you say it like that, is the only solution to just restart the Kernel every time?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) To avoid this kind of problem we added (since Spyder 3.1) a new option to clear all variables present in an IPython console before running a file.

To access that option you need to go to the menu

```
Run > Configure
```

(if you want to apply to the file you're running) or to

```
Tools > Preferences > Run
```

(if you want to apply it to all your files), then look for

```
General settings
```

and select

```
[ ] Clear all variables before execution (IPython consoles)
```